# get text of element during angular $timeout in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Note: using MEAN - Mocha, Express, Angular, and Node for the app

I am learning how to do e2e test and I built a little app to test against. One thing it does is whenever you perform an action it displays a message for X seconds and then goes away. I'm using angulars $timeout.

```
$scope.displayMessage = function(messageIn, borderColor){

        var timeoutTime = 5000; //clear the message after x seconds
        $scope.borderType = "1px solid " + borderColor;

        $scope.messages = messageIn;

        $scope.visibility = true; //reveal the div
        $timeout.cancel($scope.timeout); //cancel any previous timers

        $scope.timeout = $timeout(function(){ //Set and start new timer.

            $scope.visibility = false;
            $scope.messages = "";
        }, timeoutTime);
    };
```

Now I'm trying to test this. Currently I have

```
 it("should display message", function(done){

        var button = element(by.id("getStudents"));

        console.log("clicking button");

        var messageElem = element(by.binding("messages"));

        button.click().then(function () {

            console.log("button clicked");

            messageElem.getText().then(function(text){

               console.log("The text should equal: " + text);
            });

            //expect(messageElem.getText()).toBe("Students retrieved");
            console.log("test executed");

        });

        done();
    });
```

But it seems to be waiting until after the timeout to do the `messageElem.getText().then()` at which point the div has been cleared. The "test executed" log will print during the timeout but not the "getText()" function. I'm guessing this has something to do with angulars life cycle?

Oh and here's the HTML (in Jade format)

```
 div(ng-model="messages",ng-show = "visibility", style = "clear:both;padding-top:3em;border:{{borderType}};text-align:center;")

    h3
        {{messages}}
```

ignore my style, I was too lazy to make a css file for this test app :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using $interval instead of $timeout.

> Protractor attempts to wait until the page is completely loaded before
>   performing any action (such as finding an element or sending a command
>   to an element).

Read [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md). Details [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/49).

Comment: Ah, the details led me to do
ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true
for that particular test. It worked after that. Not sure if that's a good practice or not though.

Comment: It should work but not the best solution. You can easily replace $timeout with $interval, just use count = 1 and the rest stays the same. It's a drop in replacement. Simple.

Comment: Ok yea, it's hanging now but if I manually click the button, which protractor is supposed to do, it runs correctly. Odd

Comment: Upvoted for an interesting idea, but it didn't work for me. I'm afraid `ignoreSynchronization` is the only relatively easy way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I hacked around this using the below code block. I had a notification bar from a 3rd party node package (ng-notifications-bar) that used $timeout instead of $interval, but needed to expect that the error text was a certain value. I put used a short sleep() to allow the notification bar animation to appear, switched ignoreSynchronization to true so Protractor wouldn't wait for the $timeout to end, set my expect(), and switched the ignoreSynchronization back to false so Protractor can continue the test within regular AngularJS cadence. I know the sleeps aren't ideal, but they are very short.

```
browser.sleep(500);
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
expect(page.notification.getText()).toContain('The card was declined.');
browser.sleep(500);
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
```